# How to add 2k marker with custom bitmap icon android v2 maps

Tags: android, maps

I'm tryng to create a map with custom marker icon (bitmap and text view) for 1800 items. I'm getting out of memory error becouse my app is closed after the creation of some markers.
How can i do it?
Here is part of my code my code: 
Thank you to all!Bye

```
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE)


    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setScrollGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setTiltGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    start();
}

public void start() {
    new BackgroundTask().execute();

}


private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progress.setProgress(0);
        progress.setMessage("Loading");
        progress.show();
        cursor.moveToFirst();


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {

            if (cursor.moveToFirst())

            {
                do {

                    nome = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDbManage.KEY_NOME));
                    lati = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDbManage.KEY_LATI));
                    longi = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDbManage.KEY_LONGI));
                    prezzo = "€ "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDbManage.KEY_PREZZO));
                    id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(LocalDbManage.KEY_CONTACTID));
                    final double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lati);
                    final double longitude = Double.parseDouble(longi);


                    iconFactory.setRotation(90);
                    iconFactory.setStyle(IconGenerator.STYLE_ORANGE);
                    addIcon(iconFactory, prezzo, new LatLng(latitude, longitude));



                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
                                    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon())).
                                    position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).
                                    anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV());
                            mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                    }
                    });

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            } else

            {
                System.out.println("ERROR");  // viene eseguito l'else
            }

            Thread.sleep(1200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

        return "Lavoro Terminato!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
    }

}


private void addIcon(IconGenerator iconFactory,String text, LatLng position) {
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().
            icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconFactory.makeIcon())).
            position(position).
            anchor(iconFactory.getAnchorU(), iconFactory.getAnchorV())`


}
```

EDIT: Now i'm gettin "Could not copy bitmap to parcel blob" I don't know what it means..please help me!
Thank's

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be related to this bug report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8936

Comment: you need to expand the Answer and update Post  with appropriate code instead of Link